# Invisible infinite loop

Tags: android, kotlin, infinite-loop

I have an infinite loop in my code. Until I completely shut down the program, it is continuously writing data to my Firebase database... I am in real need, please help. I want my function MemberAdding execute just one time after button is clicked...

```
override fun MemberAdding(accountKey: String) {
    DBdatabaseName!!.reference!!.child(user!!.currentUser!!.uid).child("Group-List").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            groupKey = intent.getStringExtra("GroupKey")
            val flag = dataSnapshot.child("Groups").child(groupKey).child("members").value.toString()
            val newpath = "member" + flag

            DBdatabaseName!!.reference!!.child(user!!.currentUser!!.uid).child("Group-List").child("Groups").child(groupKey).child(newpath).setValue(accountKey)

        }


        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })

    DBdatabaseName!!.reference!!.child(user!!.currentUser!!.uid).child("Group-List").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val groupKey = intent.getStringExtra("GroupKey")
            var flag = dataSnapshot.child("Groups").child(groupKey).child("members").value.toString()
            val flag2 = flag.toInt()
            val flag3 = flag2 + 1


            DBdatabaseName!!.reference!!.child(user!!.currentUser!!.uid).child("Group-List").child("Groups").child(groupKey).child("members").setValue(flag3)

        }


        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })



    refresh()

}

private fun refresh() {
    groupKey = intent.getStringExtra("GroupKey")
    val intent = Intent(this@GroupMemberAddingActivity, GroupMemberAddingActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("GroupKey", groupKey)
    startActivity(intent)
}

}
```

at below i will also send the Adapter class that i am using

```
class GroupMemberAddingItemAdapter (context: Context, friendItemList: MutableList<FriendItem>) : BaseAdapter() {
private class  ListRowHolder (row: View? ) {
    val label: TextView = row!!.findViewById(R.id.friendName_textview) as TextView
    val addMember: Button? = row!!.findViewById(R.id.addMember_button) as Button

}

private val mInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
private var itemList = friendItemList
private var mView: View? = null
private var rowListener: GroupMemberAddingRowListener = context as GroupMemberAddingRowListener

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

    val friendName: String = itemList.get(position).friendName as String
    val friendLastName: String = itemList.get(position).friendLastName as String
    val friendemail: String = itemList.get(position).accountKey as String

    val vh: ListRowHolder
    if (convertView == null) {
        mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.groupmemberadding_row, parent, false)

        vh = ListRowHolder(mView)
        mView!!.tag = vh
    } else {
        mView = convertView
        vh = mView!!.tag as ListRowHolder
    }

    vh.label.text = "$friendName $friendLastName"
    vh.addMember!!.setOnClickListener{rowListener.MemberAdding(friendemail)}

    return mView!!

}

override fun getItem(index: Int): Any {
    return itemList[index]
}

override fun getItemId(index: Int): Long {
    return index.toLong()
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return itemList.size
}
}
```

my initial row listener is.....

```
interface GroupMemberAddingRowListener {
    fun MemberAdding (accountKey:String)
}
```

If you need any more code parts just tell me.... Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you had to debug and look where it happens, anyway I think it is inside `onDataChanged`  implementation
Since you fire:

```
 DBdatabaseName!!.reference!!.child(user!!.currentUser!!.uid).child("Group-List").child("Groups").child(groupKey).child("members").setValue(flag3)
```

setValue will happen to fire onDataChanged again.

Comment: thanks i found the solution like you said onDataChange called every time data changes on database

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem

```
DBdatabaseName!!.reference!!.child(user!!.currentUser!!.uid).child("Group-List").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
```

Line makes onDataChange is called back every time data changes...(culprit is addValueEventListener) so i changed it to

```
BdatabaseName!!.reference!!.child(user!!.currentUser!!.uid).child("Group-List").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
```

addListenerForSingleValueEvent calls the onDataChange only once than destroys the all callbacks